# How can I get the count of the amount of grouped columns as a column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table structure in MySQL like so:
`user_id, problem_id, value`

I have been successful in grouping problems together, but I would like to be able to count up the amount of columns grouped together.

This is the closest I've gotten:

```
SELECT problem_id, sum(value) as knowledge, GROUP_CONCAT(value) as attempts
FROM responses 
GROUP BY problem_id
```

It yields something similar to (more data):

<kbd>problem_id</kbd><kbd>value</kbd><kbd>attempts</kbd>
<kbd>162</kbd>           <kbd>0</kbd>       <kbd>0,0,0</kbd>      
<kbd>172</kbd>           <kbd>3</kbd>       <kbd>1,1,1</kbd>      
<kbd>166</kbd>           <kbd>1</kbd>       <kbd>1,0</kbd>

Of course, I could just do a split and count in whatever programming language I want, but I won't feel good about that.

I would be grateful if someone could help me format into something like:

<kbd>problem_id</kbd><kbd>value</kbd><kbd>attempts</kbd>
<kbd>162</kbd>           <kbd>0</kbd>       <kbd>3</kbd>           
<kbd>172</kbd>           <kbd>3</kbd>       <kbd>3</kbd>           
<kbd>166</kbd>           <kbd>1</kbd>       <kbd>2</kbd>

**EDIT!**

I got it!

```
SELECT problem_id, sum(value) as knowledge, COUNT(*) as attempts
FROM responses 
GROUP BY problem_id
```

I didn't expect the count to dynamically group here. Maybe I'm missing something.

Thank you!

Comment: post the solution as an answer and tick it

Comment: I have to wait two days...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!

SELECT problem_id, sum(value) as knowledge, COUNT(*) as attempts
FROM responses 
GROUP BY problem_id

I didn't expect the count to dynamically group here. Maybe I'm missing something.